# Wound precautions in public facilities?

Tags: wound-care, hygiene

I bicycle quite a bit, and recently had a crash where I have some fairly extensive road rash on my hip, knee, calf and shoulder area. While most are fairly scabbed over, the ones on my shoulder and knee tend to crack and bleed with movement.

What are the precautions I need to take when going to work and/or the gym? I want to protect myself against infection, but I also don't want to leave a gory trail behind me either.

Answer (score 6):

As a rule of thumb:   anywhere that blood is coming out, you should be assuming that pathogens can be transferred in.  In this situation I would smear with antibiotic ointment and wrap with sterile gauze every day (and after every shower) until the cracking-and-bleeding-with-motion stops.

Comment: keep moving though. It may sound counter-intuitive, but you want the newly formed skin to be flexible throughout the entire range of motion.